# Angular async call inside an observable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have a function to make expire date control for an Item.
In this function i create an observable that checks if the item is new or not. 
If it´s new it works as expected but when a try to get some complementary data to define if its expiring date is when it does not work well.

If the call is made for a single Item it works fine but when i try to fill a table with several item it return undefined.

I think it is a matter of the async call. The subscriber is not waiting for the inner httprequest to finish before making a new call for the next item on the table.

1- Function that meke the call to get the expire date and set the proper status.

```
 /* ValueGetter para mostrar en la tabla si la droga está vencida o vigente */
      ctlVigencia(params){
        let message: string;   
        this.ds.ctlVencimientoDroga(params.data._id, params.data.informacion.fecha.vencimientoCertificado, null)
        .subscribe(res=> {
          console.log(res);

          if(res.fAsignada == null){
            message= 'No deterninado'
          } else {
            let now = moment(new Date());
            if (res.fAsignada > now ) {
              message= 'Vigente'
            } else {
              message= ('Vencida')
            }
          }
        })
        return message
      };
```

2) Function that returns the value of the expiration date.

```
  /*Control vencimiento droga */
    ctlVencimientoDroga(idSelected: string, vencimientoCertificado: Date, modeForm?: string){
      let retesteos: Retesteo[];
      const resObs= Observable.create((observer:Observer<{[key: string]: any}>) =>{
        if (modeForm == 'nuevo'){
          observer.next({fAsignada: vencimientoCertificado})
          observer.complete();
        } else{
          this.rs.dataRetesteo.subscribe(res=>{ 
            retesteos= res;
            if (retesteos && retesteos.length == 0) {
              if(vencimientoCertificado != null) {
                observer.next({fAsignada: vencimientoCertificado});
              } else {
                observer.next(null);
              }
            }
            /* From here and down is where is the problem */
            if (retesteos && retesteos.length > 0){
              let fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado: Date;
              retesteos.forEach(element => {
                if (element.estado.estado == estadoAprobacion.Aprobado && (fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado == null || element.fVencimiento > fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado )){
                  fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado= element.fVencimiento
                }
              });
              observer.next({fAsignada: fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado});
            }
            observer.complete(); 
          });
          this.rs.getById(idSelected);
        }
      })
      return resObs;
  }
}
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite pretty much all of this to make use of operators...

```
  ctlVigencia(params){  
     // use map operator, return observable
    return this.ds.ctlVencimientoDroga(params.data._id, params.data.informacion.fecha.vencimientoCertificado, null)
    .pipe(map(res=> {
      console.log(res);
      if(res.fAsignada == null){
        return 'No deterninado'
      } else {
        let now = moment(new Date());
        if (res.fAsignada > now ) {
          return 'Vigente'
        } else {
          return 'Vencida'
        }
      }
    }));
  };


ctlVencimientoDroga(idSelected: string, vencimientoCertificado: Date, modeForm?: string){
  let retesteos: Retesteo[];
  if (modeForm == 'nuevo') {
    // return mock observable
    return of({fAsignada: vencimientoCertificado});
  }
  // return this observable and use map operator
  return this.rs.dataRetesteo.pipe(
      map(res=> { 
        retesteos = res;
        if (retesteos && retesteos.length == 0) {
          if(vencimientoCertificado != null) {
            return {fAsignada: vencimientoCertificado};
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } else {
          let fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado: Date;
          retesteos.forEach(element => {
            if (element.estado.estado == estadoAprobacion.Aprobado && (fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado == null || element.fVencimiento > fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado )){
              fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado = element.fVencimiento
            }
          });
          this.rs.getById(idSelected); // unclear why or when this should happen
          return {fAsignada: fechaUltimoRetesteoAprobado};
        }
      })
  );
}
```

then whoever wants the value from `ctlVigencia` needs to subscribe to it.

Comment: `this.rs.getById(idSelected)` is a httpRequest fired in a service i am subscribed on the service to store data on a variable and makes dataRetesteo Subject emit the http response. If i don´t call that function data Retesteo does´nt emit anything and the function does´nt work.

Comment: that's an unconventional set up but then I guess you just need to move it to above the return line or put it inside a `defer` if you want to only do that once subscribed

Comment: Thank you for your help i see i could write this much better and i learn a lot from this. But i have tried it and i get the error `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(params: any) => Observable<string>' `

Comment: looks like you need to actually call the function ... `ctlVigencia(params).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Im doing that, but it give the error i posted. I have tried this `ctlV(){return of(2)}` and try to subscribe to ctlV but it gives the same error

Comment: I should post an emoji with my hand over my face. I was not calling the function. I forgot to put `()` before `.subscribe`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: it happens, glad i could help.  feel free to mark the answer if your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value to `message` inside an asynchronous operation, but returning `message` synchronously. Try modifying `ctlVigencia` to return an `Observable` and use `map` on the response of `ctlVencimientoDroga`.

```
ctlVigencia(params): Observable<string> {
  return this.ds.ctlVencimientoDroga(params.data._id, params.data.informacion.fecha.vencimientoCertificado, null)
  .pipe(map(res=> {
    console.log(res);

    if(res.fAsignada == null){
      message= 'No deterninado'
    } else {
      let now = moment(new Date());
      if (res.fAsignada > now ) {
        message= 'Vigente'
      } else {
        message= ('Vencida')
      }
    }
    
    return message;
  }))
};
```

Please, not that I've changed `subscribe` for `pipe` and used `map`. Now, when invoking `ctlVigencia` you should `subscribe`

```
ctlVigencia(params).subscribe(message => console.log(message));
```

Comment: the operator syntax here is the older rxjs 5 syntax, now it uses `.pipe(map( ... ))`

Comment: I have tried this solution too, but have the same problem. I cant subscribe to `cltVigencia(params)` althoug i am returning the observable.

Comment: What do u mean by _I can't subscribe to cltVigencia(params)_? What is the error?